# How to reset useragent in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer, user-agent

I have to use a website that accepts only IE, but I don't want to use it, so I use Chrome and change user agent, so that website won't notice.
But I'm having problems with using other websites that recognize my browser as IE (version 6) and I would like to reset that user agent.
So my question is: is it possible to reset user agent in Chrome to default version without restarting the browser?

Comment: IE only? What kind of website is that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you know how to change it back permanently, there's two options:

1. Create a desktop shortcut to Chrome and append `--user-agent="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)"` after the `"%chromepath%/chrome.exe"` (it has to come after the quotation mark!).
2. Don't just rely on the user agent - most sites that require IE do that because they incorporate functionality that only works properly in IE. Install an extension that displays a page with the IE renderer in a Chrome tab, I recommend ["Chrome IE Tab Multi"](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fnfnbeppfinmnjnjhedifcfllpcfgeea?hl=de).

Comment: Sorry, but I might haven't wrote it clearly: I have changed useragent to IE, because of website I use and it works. Now I want to reset useragent to default because I finished using that website and I don't want to restart the browser.

Comment: Why don't you want to restart it? Can't you just reopen the tabs?

Comment: @Wojtek Unfortunately Chrome doesn't support changing the User Agent without restarting it.